# Accents in template mail subject

Tags: magento, special-characters

in base_url/app/locale/fr_FR(or whatever language)/template/email

in all template.html the subject string doesn't support special characters (generate error) and all the codes html or iso are not interpreted.

<!--@ subject l'été à  la plage  @-->

Someone has a solution ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting these characters in as html entities? We have had success putting special characters in our German emails.

A reference to characters can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried as well with Entities numbers as with Entities name but they are not interpreted.
In the body it's allright.

Did you really succeed with that with the subject ? did you use the htmlentities php method in the model which manage this output ? (thinking of it should be the right thing to do).